# How to read some bytes from BYTE*

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, arrays

I have BYTE pointer. For example the length of this BYTE array is 10.
How can I read 4 bytes from 3 position BYTE array?

Now I doing it so

```
BYTE *source = "1234567890\0";
BYTE* tmp = new BYTE[4+1]();
for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
{
tmp[i] = source[i+3];
}
```

Comment: That looks correct, what's the problem?

Comment: The new statement doesn't look correct - why the set of parantheses after the []?  Why not use string/vector depending on your needs?

Comment: void-pointers tag is mistake. I wanted type pointer

Comment: @graham.reeds The `()` is perfectly kosher, it value-initializes the array `tmp`.

Comment: @Andreas Fair enough - I've never done that (not that I can remember anyway).

Answer (score 5):

1)

```
 std::vector<BYTE> tmp1(source + 3, source + 7);
```

2)

```
BYTE tmp[5];
std::copy(source + 3, source + 7, tmp);
```

3)

```
BYTE tmp2[5];
memcpy(tmp, source + 3, 4 * sizeof(source[0]));
```

Comment: Voted this up for the std::copy. Why do I never remember that exists?